# Do linux processes actually separate cache?

Tags: memory, cache, ram

It seems like every time someone complains about how a lot of memory is being used, all of the responses claim that it is just cache, it isn't harmful, it will be reallocated when needed, etc, even when it is clearly shown that according to the memory monitoring tool it isn't some disk cache, but the "actual" usage.

I could see how disk cache is definitely not a problem, it is transparent to applications, and can simply stop being used, however does this also apply to non-disk-cache, like many claim it is? Is there somehow a separation between standard memory of a process, and memory used for cache, which can be deleted at any moment by the kernel?

It seems like then the applications would have to use different ways to allocate their memory based on its purpose, like a malloc for cache, and a standard malloc, which doesn't seem to be the case, then the only way to have actual "harmless" cache would be to constantly manually monitor the amount of free memory and drop some cache when the available memory decreases, that seems like a somewhat significant amount of work, and I highly doubt many applications go to such lengths to ensure their cache is "harmless".

Answer (score 1):

No, the kernel doesn’t manage caches for processes. Any memory allocated to a process, and used, is treated as “precious” by the kernel: it will only be removed from physical memory if its contents can be retrieved when the process needs them again.

Under Linux, processes *can* allocate memory and tell the kernel that it can reclaim it as needed, by calling [`madvise` with `MADV_FREE` advice](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html). But the process has to be fully aware of what can happen to such areas of memory.